# Evaluating Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a 15-day trial of Mathematica and need to evaluate it, and see if it can be used to help create algorithms for some games we are working on.

Are there any good resources that will teach me some basics and let me explore the application?

Comment: You're most likely going to get answers from people that Google it.

Comment: I guess there will be people that are going to wolfram it too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely you could have googled this yourself?

- [Mathematica Tutorials](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/withoff/index2.html)
- [Mathematica Tutorials](http://serc.carleton.edu/quantskills/methods/tech/btitus.html)

Answer (score 5):

Some resources that would be useful to the dedicated beginner:

http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/

- Video demonstrations and short tutorials

---

http://blog.wolfram.com/

- Wolfram Blog frequently shows what is possible with *Mathematica*, and includes code.

---

http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/Software/Downloads/Campus/TrainingMathematicaEnglish.zip

- Training Notebooks in a .zip file.

---

http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/

http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:www.mathprogramming-intro.org

- Mathematica® programming: an advanced introduction by [Leonid Shifrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565518).

  A very advanced introduction, but still approachable, and searchable (second link)

Comment: A real resurrection from the death. The question was only two and a half years old. The guy had a 15 day trial...

Comment: @Sjoerd I thought this was not discouraged.  Do you feel I should not have answered?  When I first handled *Mathematica* I would have wished for someone to direct me to useful resources rather than saying "Google it!"  The title "Evaluating Mathematica" comes up in a search, so others are likely to find this question too.

Comment: I just thought it funny. Should have added a smiley. :-)

Comment: @Sjoerd, apparently I have not made much progress on the HumorSense badge.

Comment: I like going orthogonally to "ordinary customers".  Moreover, your answer is the best one to the question, so I set +1.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica contains vast amounts of information which can leave you feeling bewildered.
A good first reference should be the goal of every new Mathematica user, for this can make or break their experience.

The first stop, the Virtual Book (found in the Help menu).
It contains both quick start material and fundamental principles, but I find it easy to get sidetracked, and it isn't heavy on down-to-earth examples.
Also, Wolfram (being a for-profit company) markets Mathematica as being all things to all people, the Virtual book is not objective about its shortcomings.

I used 
[The Student's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521717892) as a guide for a math minor: plotting, multivariable calculus, linear algebra, and working with data. In that capacity it is beautifully succinct.

It sounds like you need to browse "real world" examples—and have a limited amount of time before the trial period ends. I recommend the [Mathematica Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521004) from O'Reilly.
You can obtain the online book immediately, and
O'Reilly's cookbook style will give you a feel for the sort of programming needed to be effective in testing your gaming ideas.

Best of luck in Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

Check out this presentation by Luc Barthelet (formerly of EA Games) on his use of Mathematica in game development:

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5367/

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual presentation?  I can only find the abstract of his talk.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I misread the description.  I don't have the full presentation.